# How can I make a web page with fixed borders and a center area that scrolls?

Tags: html, css

I need some help with how to make a web page. I hope
somebody can help me.

What I would like is to have a page with a fixed border on all sides. For example a border of 50 pixels. I want the body of the page to be inside the border and for it to scroll when I move the browser window vertical scroll bar (located on the far right) and be hidden by the border.

Note I really want the scroll to be on the right hand side of the page and outside of the borders.

```
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxs
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxs
xx                                   xxs
xx                                   xxs
xx                                   xxs
xx                                   xxs
xx                                   xxs
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxs
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxs
```

Something like the above where `xx` is the border and `s` is the scroll bars.

Comment: what you tried so far? can you post your code in fiddle..

Comment: CSS: `body { border: 50px solid black;}`? _I am very confused about the position attribute and how to do this_. What is confusing you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may start with that base : http://jsfiddle.net/8r99k/
I put sample text and only a few css :

```
html{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    width:calc(100% - 100px);
    height:calc(100% - 100px);
    border:solid #eeeeee 50px;
    overflow:hidden;
}
body{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    height:100%;
    overflow:auto;
}
```

**Update**
Adding `width:100%` and `padding-right:70px` to `body`
http://jsfiddle.net/8r99k/2/

Comment: I think it's a bit different from what I am looking for. I added a picture to my question. Hope that helps.

Comment: Hmm, when I looked at your fiddle it made me feel like I need to design some webdesign with book look :D. Thanks!